# Laravel - Relations with multiple ids

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database

I have two table: 

1. **Rooms**

2. **Facilities**

The *Facilities* rooms contains the id and a varchar column. 

 The *Room* table contains a columns (*facilities_id*) with, obviously, the id from the *facilities* table. In that column I have a multiple value, separated by a comma (1,3,4).

What is the best way to make a relation between them? Like "belongsTo" relations but with multi ids.

Comment: What you need is a many-to-many relation - have a look here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: But I have ids in a column not different columns with one id each

Comment: i think you have to make different columns, otherwise its not possible at least not in laravel as far as I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Alexander M. said, would be better if you change your structure. e. g.:

```
Schema::create('facilities', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('column')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('facility_room', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('facility_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('room_id')->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('facility_id')->references('id')->on('facilities')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('room_id')->references('id')->on('rooms')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});

Schema::create('rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('column')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

#### In your Facility Model:

```
public function rooms()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Room::class);
}
```

#### In your Room Model:

```
public function facilities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Facility::class);
}
```

#### In our application:

```
$room = Room::find($id);
$facilities = $room->facilities();
```

Answer (score 4):

As @jedrzej.kurylo said, you need a many to many relation. String ids as a comma-separated list is wrong, it violates the [First normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and is extremely inconvenient to use.

So you should rethink your model structure.